# How to set default value "0" to text "Select" in DropDownList in MVC?

Tags: c#, selectedvalue

Below is the dropdownlist of Country. I want selected text "Select" which is working.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountryName", 
 new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryName, "CountryId", "CountryName"), 
 new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Now I want to set the value "0" for text "Select" which is by default selected. Currently the value for "Select" is blank as shown below.

[image]

How can I do this? The value "Select" is not in the data source. I have to access this selected value in JQuery.

I have tried with these two but none of those are working.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountryName", 
new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryName, "CountryId", "CountryName"),
"Select", new { @class = "form-control", @selected = "0" })
```

And

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountryName", 
new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryName, "CountryId", "CountryName"),
"Select", new { @class = "form-control", @selected = "0" })
```

Below is the controller code for CountryName values

```
ViewBag.CountryName = dbLMS.CountryMasters.Select(c => new { c.CountryId, c.CountryName }).OrderBy(c => c.CountryName).ToList();
```

Comment: `SelectList` has paramater `object selectedValue`. Is that what you talking about? I can't see your attached image.

Comment: did you tried with removing `@selected = "0"`?

Comment: @er-sho I have tried but it is not working as neither "Select" nor "0" are the part of datasource.

Comment: @SurajKumar, show me how you bind your contry names from controller method

Comment: @er-sho I have added controller code to the question.

Comment: @SurajKumar Please check my answer. Surely it will work for you. I do this in my case.

Comment: @SurajKumar, I added my answer below try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as follows:

**Option-1:**

```
@{
  var countrySelectList =  new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryName, "CountryId", "CountryName");

  List<SelectListItem> countrySelectListItems  = countrySelectList.ToList();
  countrySelectListItems.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "Please select", Value = "0", Selected = true }));
}

@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountryName", countrySelectListItems , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Option-2:**

In the controller method:

```
List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = dbLMS.CountryMasters.Select(a => new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = a.CountryName,
    Value = a.CountryId
}).ToList();

selectListItems.Insert(0, new SelectListItem(){Text = "Selet Country", Value = "0", Selected = true});
ViewBag.CountrySelectList = selectListItems;
```

Then in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountryName", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountrySelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: @SurajKumar Oh! I missed an `"` after Country name.You should have noticed this too.  Please use the updated code. Surly it will work now.

Comment: Selected = true should be ,Selected = true.You are missing comma.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for notice. it would work now for sure.

Comment: @SurajKumar Has it worked for you or are you facing any further problem?

Comment: It is working fine & I will accept it after some time if will not get the shorter solution from your one.

Comment: Shorter means? From controller method?

Comment: Shorter means here just in less number of lines but I already said your answer is also perfect.

Comment: Ok! Wait till then no problem :)

Comment: @SurajKumar Please check my updated answer. I have added another option for you.

Answer (score 1):

`new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryName, "CountryId", "CountryName", //Default value)`

Comment: @SurajKumar You've tried that with 0 where i have put `//Default Value`?

Comment: I have to set "0" for "Select" not the selected value. And "0" is the value of "Select".

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need a value for Select. For the model, keep the Required validation attribute.

This will ensure the value is selected. This way you dont have to check in the backend.